# How can one do rendering with Cycles using an NVIDIA RTX GPU?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

I have a NVIDIA RTX 2080. I've got an error like this:

> *CUDA binary kernel for this graphics card compute capability (7.5) not found.*

Does someone know how to enable it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot enable it since it is not yet supported. You will need to wait until it is, or attempt to build Blender with the support for Cuda 10 yourself apparently.

Answer (score 31):

**Update as of July 29th 2019**: NVIDIA RTX GPUs are now **officially** supported and can be used to accelerate renderings in Cycles using the raytracing cores of RTX cards. You can read more about this from the Blender Developers blog [here](https://code.blender.org/2019/07/accelerating-cycles-using-nvidia-rtx/).

In the past, RTX GPUs were not supported even for normal use cases unless you compile Blender from source code yourself or download a pre-compiled version of Blender 2.79 (link below)  for **Linux**. However, if you want the latest features/bug fixes you need to compile Blender from source still. People have compiled Blender this way and submitted their results to [Blender OpenData](https://opendata.blender.org/) too. As shown on [Blender OpenData](https://opendata.blender.org/) website, **RTX 2080 Ti** is currently the best GPU for rendering scenes with Cycles as of now.

If you're using Windows you can follow these instructions to compile Blender yourself:

Install Development Tools

Subversion, Git, CMake and Visual Studio must all be installed.

- Install [Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/) (free)
- Install [Subversion for Windows](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download) (SlikSVN)
- Install [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/)

  - In the installer, choose to add Git to your PATH to ensure the Git version is in the splash screen.
- Install [CMake](http://cmake.org/)

  - In the installer set the system path option to Add CMake to the system PATH for all users.
- Install [CUDA 10](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) for CUDA support in Cycles.

**Download Sources and Libraries**

Create a folder to store your copy of the Blender source code. This guide will assume your chosen folder is `C:\blender-git`.

Then open the command prompt window by hitting *Windows+R*, and then typing `cmd`, or by searching for it in the start menu. Then type the following commands.

For 64-bit Windows, check out the precompiled libraries with Subversion like this:

```
cd C:\blender-git
svn checkout https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/trunk/lib/win64_vc14  lib/win64_vc14
```

**For 32-bit Windows, use this command instead:**

```
cd C:\blender-git
svn checkout https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/trunk/lib/windows_vc14  lib/windows_vc14
```

**Download the Blender source code:**

```
cd C:\blender-git
git clone git://git.blender.org/blender.git
cd blender
git submodule update --init --recursive
git submodule foreach git checkout master
git submodule foreach git pull --rebase origin master
```

**Compile Blender**

```
cd C:\blender-git\blender
make full
```

[Source](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Windows#Quick_Setup) for the things above. In case you follow these steps and you still cannot get Cycles render anything using your RTX card, you need to follow the steps at the end of my post to rebuild/recompile Blender.

**For Linux:**

If you're on a Unix-based OS you can follow the instructions written [here](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Linux); Make sure you have installed CUDA 10 already. If you don't want to compile Blender yourself, you can instead download a version of Blender 2.79 compiled against CUDA 10 from [here](http://graphicall.org/1241).

**Update as of Dec 3rd 2018**:

As of today, the master branch of Blender natively supports NVIDIA RTX cards. So you don't have to follow the steps below anymore.

---

In case you follow the above steps and still **cannot** render anything using your RTX card, you need to do the followings to **recompile** Blender. This step works for **Windows**, **Linux** and **Mac**:

- Open *CMakeCache.txt*
- Look for *CYCLES_CUDA_BINARIES_ARCH*
- Add *sm_75* to that list
- Rebuild/Recompile Blender

Comment: It is a bit different with RTX. They are different from GTX. Support requires more than simply re-compiling. It would be already done if that was so simple. I am afraid this might not work.

Comment: @MartinZ The Blender developers have already added support for RTX cards as you can see [here](https://developer.blender.org/rB9a674a749b171959eff590d006c0bc650ce27a18) .

Comment: So that's only Cuda 10. I guess it might work. I still think there is a good chance it will not, or have you actually tried it? The full support will be trickier since there are new hardware functions in the card. It is not that straight forward - to use them additional work will need to be done. But the future is looking bright: https://twitter.com/tonroosendaal/status/1029752422485254144

Comment: @MartinZ No I didn't try it myself but some others have tried and it looks like things work fine now. I'm afraid your confusion is on on full integration of *NVIDIA OptiX* in Blender. What I can tell you is Blender will not support OptiX for a while (maybe about a year from now). So the raytracing capabilities of RTX cards won't be used in Blender but you can certainly use the cards to do normal rendering in Cycles.

Comment: @amir not sure what do you mean with "the developers added support", still I cannot use the GPU (RTX 2080) to render or viewport - downloaded latest night build!
"CUDA binary kernel for this graphics card compute capability (7.5) not found." I am not talking about Optix! - Did anyone try to compile that on Win10?

Comment: @DanielOakfield I think the only way to get it to work is to compile it yourself. Make sure you have CUDA 10 installed already. Did you try that?

Comment: I can say that these instructions don't work for getting RTX support in blender. While I was able to build, there is no option  to set the RTX GPU as the cycles compute device.

Comment: @Shaun I think I figured what the problem is. Look the last part of my post

Comment: Well crap, already deleted the source lol

Answer (score 6):

I have an NVIDIA RTX 2080 card and I had a long time to get it to work to do rendering with it. But the solution seems to be simple: all you need is to download the Linux version (from the previous answer http://graphicall.org/1241/download), copy the folder "lib" from the downloaded file"
*(I have this looks so)*

> (C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\blender-2.79-cuda 10-x86_64
>   (linux)\2.79\scripts\addons\cycles)

and paste it in the program folder

> (C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\blender
>   2.79.0\2.79\scripts\addons\cycles\lib)

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. For reference, BMW rendered on a 2080ti stock at 59 seconds

Comment: Freaky fast!!!!!

Comment: @Shaun This is because things are constantly changing in Blender and the stuff in `scripts\addons\cycles` in the  pre-compiled version of Blender 2.79 doesn't necessarily match with the stuff in the latest versions of Blender. You need to compile Blender from source so that things work smoothly as I mentioned above :)

Answer (score 3):

Found and fixed this by following the advice of one of the blender contributors here: https://blenderartists.org/t/nvidia-unveils-new-turing-architecture/1122494/105

scroll down to lazy dodo's comments from september 23 - essentially you have compile yourself and make a few edits to the makefiles.

I can confirm this works.

Tried as well. Make sure you use the 'make release' compilation command. However, while I can get the 2080ti to appear, I can't get the 2080ti to actually make anything (same error as precompiled nightly.)

Answer (score 3):

I have managed to get this working on my RTX 2080ti on Windows by downloading the latest experimental build (2.80 alpha 2 at time of writing).

These are available here: https://builder.blender.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

You have to download Blender 2.79.6 or 2.80(beta)
LINK: https://builder.blender.org/download/