# CUDA error at cuCtxCreate: illegal address | CUDA error: illegal address in cuCtxSynchronize(),line 1683

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

[image]

[image: **enter image description here**]

Hi everyone!
I have a problem with the latest daily builds

As far as I remember last working build was 24.10.18. 
On this build everything works

on all the following I get an error

---

also I have a video card rtx and I added files to the folder with cycles
(Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\cycles\lib)

```
> (filter_sm_72.cabin,  filter_sm_75.cabin,  kernel_sm_72.cabin, 
> kernel_sm_75.cabin)
```

for solving problems

```
CUDA binary kernel for this graphics card compute capacity (7.5) not found.
```

but I think the problem is not in these files, as before everything worked

again, up to ~ 24.10.18 everything worked. the following daily builds started showing an error

latest drivers installed

I would be very grateful if you help to solve the problem , thank you

Comment: So you added some random files from another build and you are now surprised it doesn't work?

Comment: these are not random files.
if I do not add these files, then I get an error
"CUDA binary kernel for this graphics card compute capacity (7.5) not found."

read more in the discussion:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119837/how-can-one-do-rendering-with-cycles-using-an-nvidia-rtx-gpu/120832?noredirect=1#comment212261_120832
___
I really like the blender
and it really renders fast on rtx2080 

but I do not have the opportunity to use it on this video card without additional intervention

I will be very grateful if they help me, because I can not solve this problem myself

Comment: Yes, what I mean is if you did not build Blender, but only copied the files it does make sense that if something is changed in the newer builds and does not match the files it will not work. There is a really good chance of this happening as you see as Cycles is actively developed all the time. If you read the comments on the answer suggesting to use the files from a build on graphicall.org, you will find a warning about that.

Comment: Thank you! I will wait for new builds (perhaps nvidia will release new drivers and they will help) and write about the results

Comment: I believe this is not a driver issue. I think there is a really good chance that you can resolve the issue and use the newest features if you build Blender with Cuda 10 yourself. On the other hand, waiting should not be very painful as there aren't too many really important new features in 2.79 daily builds. Well, exept for Cryptomatte support.

Comment: I tried to build a blender, but it didn't help me :(
In any case, I have no choice but to use previous builds .

Cryptomate is very cool :)
I would like to use it.