# Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I got blender 2.79b shut down right after the launch and i got this message from console. I re-installed blender 2.79b and Nvidia drivers again.And add blender directory opengl32.dll but nothing has changed :/

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.267]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. Tüm hakları saklıdır.

C:\Users\iTopya>"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\blender.exe" --debug-memory --debug-gpumem --debug-all > results.txt.
AL lib: (EE) UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz instead
SRNA Subclassed: 'Context'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
SRNA Subclassed: 'PropertyGroup'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Bone'
SRNA Subclassed: 'EditBone'
SRNA Subclassed: 'PoseBone'
SRNA Subclassed: 'UIList'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Mesh'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Object'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Texture'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Header'
SRNA Subclassed: 'KeyingSetInfo'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Node'
SRNA Subclassed: 'NodeInternal'
SRNA Subclassed: 'ShaderNode'
SRNA Subclassed: 'CompositorNode'
SRNA Subclassed: 'TextureNode'
SRNA Subclassed: 'WindowManager'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
SRNA Subclassed: 'RenderEngine'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
SRNA Subclassed: 'PropertyGroup'
SRNA Subclassed: 'AddonPreferences'
I0809 11:13:32.854003  2580 blender_python.cpp:186] Debug flags initialized to:
CPU flags:
  AVX2   : True
  AVX    : True
  SSE4.1 : True
  SSE3   : True
  SSE2   : True
  QBVH   : True
  Split  : False
CUDA flags:
 Adaptive Compile: False
OpenCL flags:
  Device type    : ALL
  Kernel type    : DEFAULT
  Debug          : False
  Single program : True
  Memory limit   : zu
I0809 11:13:32.873008  2580 device_cuda.cpp:2096] CUEW initialization succeeded
I0809 11:13:32.873008  2580 device_cuda.cpp:2098] Found precompiled kernels
I0809 11:13:32.977031  2580 device_opencl.cpp:58] CLEW initialization succeeded.
I0809 11:13:32.991034  2580 opencl_util.cpp:778] Enumerating devices for platform NVIDIA CUDA.
I0809 11:13:32.991034  2580 opencl_util.cpp:842] Ignoring device GeForce RTX 2070, not officially supported yet.
Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

C:\Users\iTopya>
```

Comment: Please test if this problem also occurs with Blender 2.8. I know that the RTX cards aren't supported in 2.79b, I'm not sure if this only applies to rendering or also to running Blender in general.

Comment: 2.8 runs but i need 2.79 :/

Comment: Unfortunately I can't perform miracles, we'll have to see what the other developers say to your report (https://developer.blender.org/T68425).

Comment: Have you seen this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119837/how-can-one-do-rendering-with-cycles-using-an-nvidia-rtx-gpu ?